# Linker errors for C++ framework test app

Tags: c++, xcode, linker, static-libraries, linker-errors

I would like to use the [AA+ astronomy class framework](http://www.naughter.com/aa.html) and I just want to get the sample app running (it's included in the [framework zip file](http://www.naughter.com/download/aaplus.zip) as `AATest.cpp`)

I opened Xcode, created a new project for a C++ app, and then added the `AA+.h` and `stdafx.h` files to the project since they are includes.  Then when I build the project, I get a lot of linker errors since it doesn't seem to be able to find the symbols associated with some of the sample app code.

I've tried adding the path to the `AA+.h` and `stdafx.h` files to the library and header search paths within the Build settings in Xcode, but that didn't change anything and the errors are still there.

What am I doing wrong?  This is my first time working with C++ within Xcode.  Do I have to build the AA+ framework as a static library first or can I just include it this way?

Compilation via Xcode:

```
Ld /Users/me/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AAPlus-bzgonjwgqlpgescueekcoobljdyf/Build/Products/Debug/AAPlus normal x86_64
    cd "/Users/me/Downloads/aaplus astronomy c++/Example/AAPlus"
    setenv MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 10.7
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang++ -arch x86_64 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.8.sdk -L/Users/me/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AAPlus-bzgonjwgqlpgescueekcoobljdyf/Build/Products/Debug -F/Users/me/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AAPlus-bzgonjwgqlpgescueekcoobljdyf/Build/Products/Debug -filelist /Users/me/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AAPlus-bzgonjwgqlpgescueekcoobljdyf/Build/Intermediates/AAPlus.build/Debug/AAPlus.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/AAPlus.LinkFileList -mmacosx-version-min=10.7 -stdlib=libc++ -o /Users/me/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AAPlus-bzgonjwgqlpgescueekcoobljdyf/Build/Products/Debug/AAPlus
```

Errors:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "CAANutation::TrueObliquityOfEcliptic(double)", referenced from:
      GetSolarRaDecByJulian(double, double&, double&) in main.o
      GetLunarRaDecByJulian(double, double&, double&) in main.o
  "CAADynamicalTime::DeltaT(double)", referenced from:
      GetSolarRaDecByJulian(double, double&, double&) in main.o
  "CAARiseTransitSet::Calculate(double, double, double, double, double, double, double, double, double, double)", referenced from:
      GetSunRiseTransitSet(double, double, double) in main.o
      GetMoonRiseTransitSet(double, double, double) in main.o
  "CAAMoonIlluminatedFraction::PhaseAngle(double, double, double)", referenced from:
      GetMoonIllumination(double, double&, double&, double&) in main.o
  "CAAMoonIlluminatedFraction::PositionAngle(double, double, double, double)", referenced from:
      GetMoonIllumination(double, double&, double&, double&) in main.o
  "CAAMoonIlluminatedFraction::IlluminatedFraction(double)", referenced from:
      GetMoonIllumination(double, double&, double&, double&) in main.o
  "CAAMoonIlluminatedFraction::GeocentricElongation(double, double, double, double)", referenced from:
      GetMoonIllumination(double, double&, double&, double&) in main.o
  "CAACoordinateTransformation::Ecliptic2Equatorial(double, double, double)", referenced from:
      GetSolarRaDecByJulian(double, double&, double&) in main.o
      GetLunarRaDecByJulian(double, double&, double&) in main.o
  "CAASun::ApparentEclipticLatitude(double)", referenced from:
      GetSolarRaDecByJulian(double, double&, double&) in main.o
  "CAASun::ApparentEclipticLongitude(double)", referenced from:
      GetSolarRaDecByJulian(double, double&, double&) in main.o
  "CAADate::CAADate(double, bool)", referenced from:
      PrintTime(double, char const*) in main.o
  "CAADate::CAADate(long, long, double, bool)", referenced from:
      PrintSunAndMoonInfo(int, int, int, double, double) in main.o
  "CAAMoon::EclipticLatitude(double)", referenced from:
      GetLunarRaDecByJulian(double, double&, double&) in main.o
  "CAAMoon::EclipticLongitude(double)", referenced from:
      GetLunarRaDecByJulian(double, double&, double&) in main.o
  "CAADate::Get(long&, long&, long&, long&, long&, double&) const", referenced from:
      PrintTime(double, char const*) in main.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: I've tried g++ via the command line and it gives the same errors.  I've also made sure that Xcode is including the standard libraries.

Comment: Can you paste your compilation command?

Comment: Xcode handles compilation and I've posted what it uses for clang++

Comment: From their documentation (`AA+.htm`): 
_"To use the classes in your code simple include `AA*.cpp` in your project and `#include AA*.h` in which ever of your modules needs to make calls to the classes."_ Notice the **regex \***.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice the beggining of your question. Do you just want to compile it and run? Does it need to be in XCode? If not, you can use `cmake`. The authors provided a `CMakeLists.txt`. Have you used `cmake` before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### XCode

You can do the following in XCode:

1. Create a new project `AATest`
2. Copy your `aaplus/` folder with the framework code into your project folder
3. In your XCode project, hold <kbd>control</kbd> and click over **Source**
4. Select **Add > Existing Files...**
5. Select `aaplus/` folder and **Add** it to your project
6. Build.

The executable will be in `build/Debug/AATest`.

### Alternative

As the project includes a file `CMakeLists.txt`, you can build your program using `cmake`. Inside your framework folder, run the following commands on your terminal:

```
mkdir build/
cd build/
cmake ..
make
```

Comment: Thanks Victor, your comment about using cmake did the trick!  That generated an Xcode project that I could just build and run and it worked perfectly.  Thanks again!!

Comment: @ZeNewb - I'm glad it worked :) I will add `cmake` to my answer.